# vb.NET (for ASPX page): Parse a string to a date

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to make this line work:

```
MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2/8/2013 11:59:00 AM", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

I'm getting `date/time` strings from spreadsheets in the above format, and I can't control that. There's a ton of help online, including this site, about converting strings to dates, and I've tried them all, but I keep getting this error :

```
"System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

I"m just about ready to write my own custom parser, but that doesn't seem very elegant. Is there some built-in way to convert a string like mine into the `date/time` format I need?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is wrong.  You're entering a date in `d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format, but telling it to expect a date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.  The two do not match exactly, so [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) is quite rightly throwing an exception at you.

Try:

```
MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2/8/2013 11:59:00 AM", "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

This tells it to expect the following characters:

```
Integer from 1 through 31 (depending on the length of the month)
/ character
Integer from 1 through 12
/ character
4 digit year
Space
Integer from 1 through 12
: character
Integer from 00 through 59
: character
Integer from 00 through 59
Space
Two character meridian specifier ("AM" or "PM")
```

For more info on the datetime format strings, check out [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Doggon it, I read the directions for the ParseEstract function on two different web sites, and I misread it both times. My bad, answer was staring me in the face. Thanks.

Comment: @Stanton No problems.  We all make mistakes :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the string format to match what you are passing in. You seem to be passing in something more like this:

```
"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

Give that a try and see how it works.  Note that you need to use `MM` for months--'mm' is used for minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a fool (see above comment).